# UBCF rating predict for binary data in R package recommenderlab

Tags: r, predictive-models, computational-statistics, recommender-system, rating

In the R package recommenderlab's predict function for binary data (specifically unary for market basket analysis), why does the code do the following for the weighted UBCF model?

```r
ratings <- t(sapply(1:nrow(newdata),
                    FUN = function(i) {
                      r_neighbors <- as(model$data[neighbors[[i]]], "dgCMatrix")
                      drop(as(crossprod(r_neighbors, s_uk[, i]), "matrix")) /
                        colSums(!dropNAis.na(r_neighbors))
                      }
                    )
             )
```

My doubt is about the `colSums(!dropNAis.na(r_neighbors))` part because according to the formula in the documentation:

[image: Original]

That tells me a good prediction for user a rating for item l is the i-nearest users' rating mean for item l, weighted by the i-nearest users' similarities with user a.

But I believe the code is attempting to do:

[image: What it seems to me]

That is, the i-nearest users' similarities (with user a) mean for item l, weighted by the i-nearest users' ratings, which is the sum of non-NA (1's) ratings. Since the non-NA ratings are 1's, it is just the mean of the similarities of users where item l is active (bought, in market basket analysis).

Can someone help me understand?